# What's the VOBsub subtitle format?

Tags: subtitle, vob

Where can I find documentation/sample code of the VOBsub subtitles format? The one that's an .idx and a .sub file.

I need to create a program that generates those subtitles. I've been looking on Google but only found how to rip them from DVD.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

> VOBsub extracts the DVD subtitles raw [PES](http://dvd.sourceforge.net/dvdinfo/pes-hdr.html) from a DVD and dumps this to a .sub file. It also creates a .idx Index file with the times and byteoffsets for each and every single subtitle. The format has support for multiple tracks and can also be embedded in MP4 (by Nero) and Matroska files.

- [Technical specs vobsub](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=VOBsub)
- [Technical specs from Matroska.org](https://matroska.org/technical/subtitles.html#images-subtitles)
- [Example files: Specs_and_idx-sub_files.rar](http://www.mediafire.com/file/jjkkh9iak234m40/Specs_and_idx-sub_files.rar)

Have a look at these open source implementations:

- [BDSup2Sub](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=145277) (Java)
- [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit) (C#)
- [guliverkli by gabest](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/) (C++) check out VSFilter and VSRip; original implementation
- [Son2VobSub.rar](http://www.findthatfile.com/search-5565062-hRAR/winrar-winzip-download-459-son2vobsub-rar.htm) (C++)

And then there are the media players like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). You can also check out these threads on doom9:

- http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-87171.html
- http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-99815.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach would be to have a look at the sourcecode of some of the open-source media players. Some of them will have the code to interpret an .idx or .sub subtitle file.

This might be a useful starting point:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/